# Bash error: Integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell, pipeline

In the sections below, you'll see the shell script I am trying to run on a UNIX machine, along with a transcript.

When I run this program, it gives the expected output but it also gives an error shown in the transcript. What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

First, the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while read A B C D E F
do
    E=`echo $E | cut -f 1 -d "%"`
    if test $# -eq 2
    then
        I=`echo $2`
    else
        I=90
    fi
    if test $E -ge $I
    then
        echo $F
    fi
done
```

And the transcript of running it:

```
$ df -k | ./filter.sh -c 50
./filter.sh: line 12: test: capacity: integer expression expected
/etc/svc/volatile
/var/run
/home/ug
/home/pg
/home/staff/t
/packages/turnin
$ _
```

Comment: you can easily see the source of your problem by using the shell debug/trace faciltiiy, `set -vx`. ( `set +vx` turns it off). Good luck.

Comment: Incidentally, you want to avoid the [useless use of `echo`](http://iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo): simply `I=$2` is cheaper, faster, shorter to type, and more robust than `I=$(echo "$2")` (or the equivalent in backticks that you have which is harder to type with  proper formatting here, modulo  improper quoting).

Comment: @tripleee: Should be `I="$2"` rather than `I=$2`

Comment: @KeithThompson Actually, the RHS of an assignment is handled specially, so the double quotes are not required (but of course, they are harmless). But for consistency, indeed, perhaps I should have included them.  Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the line that says:

```
if test $E -ge $I
```

temporarily place the line:

```
echo "[$E]"
```

and you'll find something very much non-numeric, and that's because the output of `df -k` looks like this:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      954316620 212723892 693109608  24% /
udev               10240         0     10240   0% /dev
: :
```

The offending line there is the first, which will have its fifth field `Use%` turned into `Use`, which is definitely *not* an integer.

A quick fix may be to change your usage to something like:

```
df -k | sed -n '2,$p' | ./filter -c 50
```

or:

```
df -k | tail -n+2 | ./filter -c 50
```

Either of those extra filters (`sed` or `tail`) will print only from line 2 onwards.

---

If you're open to not needing a special script at all, you could probably just get away with something like:

```
df -k | awk -vlimit=40 '$5+0>=limit&&NR>1{print $5" "$6}'
```

The way it works is to only operate on lines where both:

- the fifth field, converted to a number, is at least equal to the limit passed in with `-v`; and
- the record number (line) is two or greater.

Then it simply outputs the relevant information for those matching lines.

This particular example outputs the file system *and* usage (as a percentage like `42%`) but, if you just want the file system as per your script, just change the `print` to output `$6` on its own: `{print $6}`.

Alternatively, if you *do* the percentage but without the `%`, you can use the same method I used in the conditional: `{print $5+0" "$6}`.

Comment: Oh cool it works. Just one question: Is my problem caused by the header?

Comment: @Fahad, almost certainly, yes.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Now I get it. In the first line I get "Use" as well, which is certainly not an integer. Thanks heaps :)